# Swapping elements inside adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm making a file explorer synchronizing a directory in ftp, I would like that when a new item is downloaded it is displayed first in my recyclerview. For that I use sharedpreferences to store the new files and so I display or not a dot next to it to notify that it is new. Then I want to place it first at the begining of my MutableList, everything goes well except when I have to update with notifyItemMoved() which gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{e8a722f VFED..... ......ID 0,60-1536,1098 #7f080104 app:id/main_folder_recycle_view}, adapter:fr.frd.calvezdocs.adapter.DirAdapter@f17203c, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager@31331c5, context:fr.frd.calvezdocs.MainActivity@5181ba0
```

Here is the code in my onBindViewHolder() :

```
    val isRead: String? = prefNewDir.getString(currentDir.absolutePath, null) 

    if (isRead!=null) {               
        holder.DirIsRead.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        println("before : " + items[0])
        items.remove(currentDir)
        items.add(0,currentDir)
        println("after : "+items[0])
        // Can't update the recyclerview
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    } else 
        holder.DirIsRead.visibility = View.GONE
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder` is the method the adapter calls when it's displaying the list, and it's passing you a `ViewHolder` so you can update it to display a particular item in the list.

It's not the place to be doing stuff like calculating that the list has changed, and requesting a new layout, which is why you're getting an exception. You also definitely shouldn't be changing the `items` dataset while the `RecyclerView` is trying to display part of it!

Really, your adapter should have some kind of `setData` function, where you pass in updated data, and it can do stuff like working out what's moved, sorting the list for display, keeping a list of what's new and needs a highlight dot, etc. And that function can call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, or one of the more specific (and better) update functions as appropriate.

When you get new data (e.g. when you're storing a new file in the `SharedPreferences`) that's when you should be pushing an update to the adapter, so it can do what it needs to do, and refresh if necessary. You can even make it a simple `update()` call that passes nothing, and the adapter does all the `SharedPreferences` lookup you're currently doing in `onBindViewHolder`, if you want. And it'll be a lot more efficient than doing these lookups every time an item in the list is drawn

(I'd really recommend against what you're doing with `SharedPreferences` too, but maybe it complicates things less than I'm imagining. I'd still recommend trying to make your adapter work with a basic list internally, though - pass one in, so it doesn't need to know how the rest of the app is persisting data)